# When I try to create a drop down list, when the page refreshes the selected data defaults to it original state?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown, dropdownbox

How do I get my selection to stick when I click save, and not have it default to its original state?

Example:
`<select id="language" name="language"`
`<option value=""></option`
`<option value="One">One</option`
`<option value="Two">Two</option`
`<option value="Three">Three</option`
`</select>`
So if I select "Two" option, then click save. It would default to the blank option.

Please Advise

I was expecting the drop down list to keep what you have selected when you save.

Comment: click SAVE means what actually? Is it save into some database?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you wanted and the best way is determined by your actual needs.

## 1. SUBMIT

Since you have a `select` tag and a SAVE button, it is quite possible that you have a `form` that is submitted or a request is being sent in some different manner to the server, possibly AJAX. Your `select` has a `name` which is set to `language`, so, your request most probably has a `language` parameter.

So, your server gets the request and then responds with the same dropdown (among others). On your server-side you can check whether a `language` parameter was received and if so, whether it is equal to any of the options. If you use PHP, then you could have the following on your server:

```
<select id="language" name="language">
    <?php
    $options = ["", "One", "Two", "Three"];
    foreach ($options as $option) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option ?>"<?php echo ((($_REQUEST["language"] ?? null) === $option)) ? "" : " selected"; ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Of course, your might be using some other server-side language/technology, this is just an illustration of the idea you will need to apply.

## 2. Loading from the database or other storage

Since you have a SAVE button, you might want to save things on the database (or other server-side storage) when it is being clicked. If that's the case, then you can modify the generation of your markup to mark the chosen option as `selected` based on the database and, if your form is posted, then first save it in your database. This would be an option that works across browsers for different users.

## 3. Storing in localStorage or `sessionStorage`

You can also specify a function that stores the chosen value in a storage, like

```
function storeLanguage(myStorage, theLanguage) {
    myStorage.setItem("language", theLanguage);
}
```

and then create a change event listener for your dropdown, like:

```
document.getElementById("language").addEventListener("change", function() {
    storeLanguage(localStorage, this.value); //you could use sessionStorage here instead, if you prefer that
});
```

and, you can add a loadHandler to `body`, like:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("language") !== undefined) {
    document.body.addEventListener("load", function() {
        document.getElementById("language").value = localStorage.getItem("language");
    });
}
```